# Vlookup populating blank cells

Tags: excel, vlookup, autofill

I'm doing a vlookup to populate cells in WB A with values in WB B.All of the IDs in WB A are not found in WB B. However, when the Vlookup encounters an ID that's in WB A but not in B, rather than returning a blank cell in WB A it returns a duplicate value of the cell above. 
Any ideas why this may be happening? I've done this with no problems countless times until now and don't think i've done anything differently.![enter image description here][1]

Comment: Hi there, image is missing.  Also please have it show your formula as well as the data range

Comment: please add your formula of vlookup plz.

Answer (score 0):

VLOOKUP  has a fourth parameter called Range_Lookup  which can be set to TRUE or FALSE

```
VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])
```

You must set this to FALSE if only exact matches are to be returned.

If set to True or omitted , it will returned the closest match

Example:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1, Sheeet2!A:B, 2, FALSE)
```